# Tag <object> in IE and board around it

Tags: jquery, css, object, iframe, datatable

I'm using Jquery datatable pageResize plugin. Inside it has  for fake scroll. It works for Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 10+ it produces frame with gray outline. How to disable this effect?

```
 <div class="table_container" style="height: 300px; position: relative;">
     <object data="about:blank" type="text/html" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; z-index: -1;">
     </object>
 </div>
```

Comment: I t would be helpful if you could reproduce this in a fiddle. There is not much to go for, not even what version of the scroller extension nor version of DataTables.

Comment: Sorry, not so easy to reproduce actually, but I've spoke with creators they told me will be changed to <iframe> in future releases. Seems like they aware about the issue.

Comment: that sounds just great! In the meantime It should be possible to style the <object> tag or its content in IE.

Comment: It's not content problem. only <object> itself. Cant find yet right condition on JSfiddle